# Calculation time delta in pivot table - Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pivot, timedelta

By using python's pandas pivot table with following raw data, I want accumulate the sum of time between states. I am searching the time of State DOWN and RUNNING filtered by ID and OPERATOR_ID.

| ID | STATE | DATE | EVENT | OPERATOR_ID | SESSION_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 321 | STOP | 26.10.2021 14:02 | Down |  | 1 |
| 123 | RUNNING | 26.10.2021 14:14 | UP | Operator_1 | 2 |
| 123 | STOP | 26.10.2021 14:35 | Down |  | 3 |
| 321 | RUNNING | 26.10.2021 16:02 | UP | Operator_2 | 4 |
| 321 | STOP | 26.10.2021 16:12 | Down |  | 1 |
| 321 | RUNNING | 26.10.2021 16:13 | UP | Operator_1 | 4 |
| 321 | STOP | 26.10.2021 16:16 | Down |  | 1 |

| ID | STATE | OPERATOR_ID | Time_in_State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 321 | RUNNING | Operator_1 | 00:03 |
|  |  | Operator_2 | 00:10 |
|  |  |  | 00:13 |
|  | STOP |  | 02:01 |
| 123 | RUNNING |  | 00:21 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

First attempt:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('StateMonthly.csv', sep=';', header=1, parse_dates=['DATE'], index_col='DATE')

table_time = pd.pivot_table(df, index = ['ID', 'OPERATOR_ID', 'STATE'], values = ['DATE'], aggfunc = {'DATE':np.sum})
```

The sum is totally nonsense. I have to build the delta of two rows and add them up... but my python skills aren't good enough :(

Further problem: First and last delta calculation is not possible, so I have to set it manually to the start and end of month I think.

Comment: "*I want accumulate the sum of time between states*" - you mean from the UP timestamp until the DOWN timestamp? "*filtered by ID and OPERATOR_ID*" - you mean *grouped by* ID and OPERATOR_ID?

Comment: Yes, from UP to DOWN because this is state RUNNING.
I gave an example (the second table).

I'm searching the time of each ID and Operator in States DOWN and RUNNING (this information is redundant with the Event column)